# vue router. How to know if navigation I was a clicked link or programmatic

Tags: vue-router

I must know if the navigation was triggered by JavaScript using

```
this.$router.push("...")
```

or clicked on a link like

```
<router-link :to="...">
```

How can I figure out this?

Comment: Why do you need to know?  Could you, for example, have the URLs be slightly different (for example, an otherwise unused query parameter) so you could distinguish them?

Comment: There is no way to tell. They both do the same thing. They lazy-load the component using the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between them because of `<router-link :to="...">` will also resolve in `this.$router.push("...")`.

To know the difference between them you can use query params like `this.$router.push("link?clicked=F")` and `<router-link :to="link?clicked=T">`. Using this query params you can easily distinguish between clicked and non clicked router link.

To access the query param use `this.$route.query.<param-name>` like `this.$route.query.clicked` will give `T` of `F` accordingly.